# error: The getter 'tasks' isn't defined for the type 'StatefulWidget'. (undefined_getter at [todoey_flutter] lib\widgets\tasks_list.dart:30)

Tags: flutter, dart

I got an error by using a getter. widget.tasks....
Please have a look at the image and the code belo.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'task_tile.dart';
import 'package:todoey_flutter/models/task.dart';
import 'package:todoey_flutter/screens/tasks_screen.dart';

class TaskList extends StatefulWidget {
  TaskList({required this.tasks});

 final List tasks;

 @override
 _TaskListState createState() => _TaskListState();
 }

class _TaskListState extends State {
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return TaskTile(
      taskTitle: widget.tasks[index].name,
      isChecked: widget.tasks[index].isDone,
      checkboxCallback: (checkboxState) {
        setState(() {
          widget.tasks[index].toggleDone();
        });
      },
    );
  },
  itemCount: widget.tasks.length,
);
}
```

[image: The image of Android Studio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the type of widget you want to create state for, from your stateful widget to the state class:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'task_tile.dart';
import 'package:todoey_flutter/models/task.dart';
import 'package:todoey_flutter/screens/tasks_screen.dart';

class TaskList extends StatefulWidget {
  TaskList({required this.tasks});

 final List tasks;

 @override
 _TaskListState createState() => _TaskListState();
 }

class _TaskListState extends State<TaskList> { // ADD <TaskList> 
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return TaskTile(
      taskTitle: widget.tasks[index].name,
      isChecked: widget.tasks[index].isDone,
      checkboxCallback: (checkboxState) {
        setState(() {
          widget.tasks[index].toggleDone();
        });
      },
    );
  },
  itemCount: widget.tasks.length,
);
}
```